# Internet Explorer 7+8 Error - jQuery .ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

I have been attempting to debug an error in an ajax form for the last several hours with no luck.  My function looks correct and I am getting a strange error in IE about a line that is not even in any part of my code, jQuery or similar.  I am testing in VMWare fusion and both IE tester and regular version I get the following error. This has been tested in every other browser and works perfectly.  Also something I noticed is the line number of the code mentioned will change at random based on IE Version.

```
Line: 134926530
Char: 1
Error: Syntax error
Code: 0
```

Javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
                    url: "proxy.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: serialized,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data.search(/invalid/i) != -1) {
                            alert('The email address you supplied is not valid.  please fix before yo uacan subscribe to this list.');
                        }
                        else
                        {       
                            $("#nduiik-nduiik").val("Thank you!");
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                             $("#email-list").animate({top : "-200px"}, 500);
                                     }, 
                                    1500);
                            var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-2400393-45");
                        pageTracker._trackPageview("/newsletter_signup");
                        }

                    }

                });
        }); // end of ajax
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, could there be an extra comma at the end of your last `$.ajax` option?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.html',
    type: 'post',
    success: function() { }, <-- something like this?
});
```

Comment: +1, I was guessing an extra comma somewhere. Would love to see some code from the OP though